# Undefined index error (but the indexes exist)

Tags: php, laravel

I have this to get some info from an API:

```
$postInformation = (new postInformation)->handle(['field' => 'slug', 'value' => $this->slug]);
$postId =  $postInformation['id'];
```

Then I have this:

```
$data =
            array_map(fn ($category) => [
                'post_id' => $postId,
                'category_id' => $category['id'],
                'category_name' => $category['name']['en'],
            ], $postInformation['categories']['data'], ['category_id', 'category_name']);

DB::table('post_categories  ')->insertOrIgnore($data);
```

But it shows an error when I refresh the page:

```
{message: "Undefined array key "id"", exception: "ErrorException",…} exception: "ErrorException" file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Post.php" line: 59 message: "Undefined array key \"id\"" trace: [{,…}, {file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Postl.php", line: 59,…},…].
```

If I hardcode the $postId like, "        `$postId =  5;`" it shows:

```
file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Post.php"
line: 69
message: "Undefined array key \"categories\""
```

It seems that those indexes exist, this dump (dd($postInformation);) shows:

```
^ array:38 [
  "id" => 5
  .....
  "categories" => array:2 [
    "data" => array:15 [
      0 => array:3 [
        "id" => 6
        "name" => array:1 [
          "en" => "General"
        ]
        "on_request" => 0
      ]
      1 => array:3 [
        "id" => 14
        "name" => array:1 [
          "en" => "Tuts"
        ]
        "on_request" => 0
      ]
  ]
 
    ....
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following

```
$postId = $postInformation['id'];
$data = array_map(function ($category) use ($postId) {
    return [
        'post_id' => $postId,
        'category_id' => $category['id'],
        'category_name' => $category['name']['en'],
    ];
}, $postInformation['categories']['data']);

print_r($data);
```

It will print out this, it this what you were expecting?

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 5
            [category_id] => 6
            [category_name] => General
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [post_id] => 5
            [category_id] => 14
            [category_name] => Tuts
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks, but it shows the same issue like that "message: "Undefined array key "id"", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/var/www/html/app/NovaPost.php"
line: 59
message: "Undefined array key \"id\""
trace: [{,…}, {file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Post.php", line: 59,…},…]"

Comment: If you get this error on `$postId = $postInformation['id'];` this means that you don't have in some cases the ID key in $postInformation. Can you paste the code of NovaPost.php at line 59? It's complicated to help you debugging from a StackOverflow thread. :)

Comment: The line is this one: $postId =  $postInformation['id'];. But Im just testing for a specific post, that has the id, the id 5. So not really understanding. Thanks

Comment: Try to print_r every time the $postInformation to verify what you get instead of the id key ...and double-check if there are any typos.

Comment: It seems that works with data_get($postInformation, 'id'). But now it shows {message: "array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given",…}
exception: "TypeError"
file: "/var/www/html/app/Nova/Post.php"
line: 69
message: "array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, null given". Do you know what can be the issue? Thanks

Comment: ...so $postInformation['categories'] is null, not an array.

Comment: Im using like this "data_get($postInformation, 'categories.data'),". Its not correct like this with the data_get approach?

Comment: $data =
                array_map(function ($category) use ($postId) {
                    return [
                       ...
                    ];
                }, data_get($postInformation, 'categories.data'), ['category_id', 'category_name']);

Comment: If I use like this instead "$data = array_map(function ($category) use ($postId) { return [ ... ]; }, $postInformation['categories']['data'], ['category_id', 'category_name'])" it shows: message: "Undefined array key \"categories\"".